# Do there exist nonequal unit vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $x_1^*Ax_1=x_2^*Ax_2=\mu$?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, svd

For any given $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, does there
always exists a pair $x_1\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $x_2\in\mathbb{C}^n$ such that the followings are satisfied:

1. $\|x_1\|=\|x_2\|=1$ (here $\|\cdot\|$ is second norm),
2. $x_1^*Ax_1=x_2^*Ax_2=\mu$ for some nonzero $\mu\in\mathbb{C}$,
3. $x_1\neq x_2$.

My attempt:

1. First of all I want to prove that $x_1=Ux_2$ for some unitary $U$.

Lets say $x_1=Tx_2$ for some $T\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, then using SVD on $T$, we get $x_1=U_T\Sigma_TV_T^*x_2$. We know that $\|x_1\|=\|U_T\Sigma_TV_T^*x_2\|=\|\Sigma_TV_T^*x_2\|=\|V_T^*x_2\|$, let $x_3=V_T^*x_2$ then from last equality we will get $x_3^*(\Sigma_T^2-I)x_3=0$, which means $\Sigma_T=I$, thus $x_1=U_TV_T^*x_2=Ux_2$, where $U=U_TV_T^*$.

2. Then second requirement becomes  $x_1^*Ax_1=x_1^*UAU^*x_1=\mu$, or equivalently $x_1^*(A-\mu I)x_1=x_1^*(UAU^*-\mu I)x_1=0$. From here I couldn't continue.

---

Background: In Matlab, I generate random $A$, so it is not zero, identity or diagonal matrix with probability $1$. First I plot numerical range of $A$, i.e., $x^∗Ax$ for all unit vectors $x$, and then pick up any point $\mu$ inside that numerical range. Then solve inverse numerical range problem, so given  $A$ and $\mu$, find unit vector $x$ that satisfies $x^∗Ax=\mu$. I just wonder if this $x$ is unique or not? I consider $x$ and $-x$ to be the same answer.

Comment: If $A$ is the identity matrix then we can take any two distinct real unit vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Are you looking for any example of $A$ such that this exists? Then any $A$ with at least a degenerate eigenvalue will do, say $A=\mathrm{diag}(1,1,2)$, $x_1=(1,0,0)$, $x_2=(0,1,0)$.

Comment: I wonder if for any $A$ such pair $x_1$ and $x_2$ exists?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have reformulated the question, so that identity matrix case is included

Comment: If you take $A = 0$, then $x^{*}Ax = 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$. On the other hand, if $x_1^*Ax_1=\mu\neq 0$, then we may choose $x_2=-x_1$.

Comment: @SangchulLee my question comes from Matlab, lets say that we generate random $A$, it is not equal to zero or identity matrix with probability one. So I just want to know if there are more that one unit vector $x$ such that $x^*Ax=\mu$, and I don't consider $x_2=-x_1$ case

Comment: @user1551 In Matlab, I first plot numerical range, i.e., $x^*Ax$ for all unit vectors $x$, and then pick up any point $\mu$ inside that numerical range. Then solve inverse numerical range problem, so given $A$ and $\mu$, find unit vector $x$ that satisfies $x^*Ax=\mu$. I just wonder if this $x$ is unique or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, if you pick a value $\mu\ne0$ from the numerical range of $A$, the unit vector $x$ that gives $x^\ast Ax=\mu$ can be unique up to a sign. For example, consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&i\\ i&-1},
$$
so that $x^\ast Ax=|z_1|^2-|z_2|^2+2i\Re(\overline{z}_1z_2)$ when $x=(z_1,z_2)^\top$. If $x$ is a unit vector, then $x^\ast Ax=1$ only if $x=\pm(1,0)^\top$.

Of course, $x$ is not unique in some other cases, such as when $A=I_n$ with $n\ge2$.

Comment: I wonder if you mind to chat a little bit about this problem with me? I wanted to open chat room, but couldn't find that option here

Comment: @Lee I'm sorry. I don't use chat rooms.